# woocommerce thank you redirect after 3 seconds

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am using this snippet to redirect the customer after making the purchase.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'pfwp_redirect_woo_checkout');
function pfwp_redirect_woo_checkout( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'https://********/thank-you-for-your-purchase/';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

the page content is GIF and an alert section that says thank you for your purchase and a button.

I want the default page of the woocommerce thank you to be the first one and after 3 seconds it redirects the customer to the custom page.

```
$url = 'https://********/thank-you-for-your-purchase/';
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but my advice would be to copy the WC thank_you template into your theme and have a query var trigger JS/jQuery on a timer.